# dataGridView is not displaying the list

Tags: c#

I' have been trying to learn linq expressions.

I have this code that doesn't displaying the list in the dataGridView:

```
var x = bd.countries.OrderBy(a => a.description).TakeWhile(b => b.IdCountry<= 500);
```

In this line:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = x.ToList();
```

I get this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[App3BD.pais] TakeWhile[pais](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[App3BD.pais], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[App3BD.pais,System.Boolean]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Can you help me please?
Thanks,
Paulo Praca

Answer (score 1):

TakeWhile is not implemented in LINQ to Entities so you cannot use it before you are actually materializing your query. Use `Where` instead.

```
var x = bd.countries.OrderBy(a => a.description).Where(b => b.IdCountry<= 500);
```

Comment: `Where` works but is not equivalent to `TakeWhile`. `TakeWhile` stops at the first non-satisfied condition. They would be equivalent if the sort order would be by `IdCountry`.

Comment: Indeed @OlivierJacot-Descombes, it is not equivalent to `TakeWhile`. If I'm thinking about it, it wouldn't matter if we had `OrderBy(x=>x.IdCountry)` before the `Where` because it would not stop going through all the table rows before returning the results. I may be mistaken (it's just a supposition). because the database engine can be smart enough to implement such a logic.